# What type of Pokemon is Beedrill?

Tags: pokemon

I've been arguing with my friend for a while about this.
But is Beedrill classified as a wasp or a bee Pokemon?

Its name is indeed "Bee"drill, but its shape is one of a wasps'.

[image][image]

Comment: Its "species" is identified as "Poison Bee Pokemon" in both English and Japanese for what that's worth. See [its Bulbapedia article](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Beedrill_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) for more details.

Comment: If you are trying to relate this to real life, then surely we must go back to the roots http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weevil

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beedrill is a bee. It's classified as such in the Pokedex and its in the name as well.

Answer (score 7):

Beedrill is called Poison Bee Pokemon, but Kingdra is called Dragon Pokemon when it's clearly a seahorse. I'd say it's based off a wasp, due to the fact that its main feature is a sting. Bees sting once then die, but wasps can sting as many times as they want, just like Beedrill. Hence the 3 stingers.

Comment: Kingdra isn't a seahorse, but a close relative called the [seadragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_seadragon). Dragalge is also based on one (specifically, the [leafy seadragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leafy_seadragon)).

Answer (score 2):

Beedrill is a dual-type Bug/Poison Pokemon. In your form of question of if he is a Bee or a Wasp, he is indeed a Bee.